How can I establish constraints in QGIS forms?
I need to establish some constraints in QGIS form. I need to constraint the values in a field based in the value of another field:
If field X = 1, and if field Y > 0, I need a message that says:

the value of Y has to be 0

I tried with the expression CASE WHEN  "x" = '1' THEN  "Y" = '0' END in the value by default but it didn't work.
